# PHP Elseif always returning false, multiple conditions

Tags: php, if-statement, boolean, multiple-conditions

I'm trying to make an helper php-function that's going to return true/false if the user got right access level. The access level is set when the user logs in. The problem is that the function always return false. The function is located in a "class" php-file that's included(with include_once) on the page I want to use it.

I'm kinda new to php, but the if conditions seems to be right.

I have tested to log in as admin and "economy", but it doesn't return true.
I also have tried to echoing the value that is sent as an parameter and even checking that the access level is right(by echoing the value) before the elseif statement.

```
    const AccessLevelUser = 0;      
    const AccessLevelAdmin = 1;     
    const AccessLevelManager = 2; 
    const AccessLevelEconomy = 3;

    public static function hasAccessLevel($requiredAccess) {
        //file_put_contents('logg.txt', $logg);

        if( !isset($_SESSION['accesslevel']) ) {
            header("location:index.php?location=login");
            exit;
        }elseif ( $requiredAccess == AccessLevelAdmin && $_SESSION['accesslevel'] == AccessLevelAdmin ) {
                echo "Admin True";
                return true;

        }elseif( $requiredAccess == AccessLevelEconomy && ($_SESSION['accesslevel'] == 3 || $_SESSION['accesslevel'] == 1) ) {
                echo "Economy True";
                return true;

        }elseif( $requiredAccess == AccessLevelManager && ($_SESSION['accesslevel'] == 2 || $_SESSION['accesslevel'] == 1) ) { 
                echo "Manager True";
                return true;

        }elseif( $requiredAccess == AccessLevelUser && ($_SESSION['accesslevel'] == 0 || $_SESSION['accesslevel'] == 1) ) { 
                echo "User True";
                return true;
        }else{
                echo "FALSE!";
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If this is in a class, you'll need to prefix those constants with `self::`. PHP will have been raising notices about this - try increasing your `error_reporting` level

Comment: @iainn Thanks! Now it works. I can't believe I didn't think about that, been stuck with this part for a couple of days.